# Add a column to sheet and apply this excel formula in whole column using python pandas or any other better library

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Need to Add a column to an existing sheet of excel file and apply this excel formula in whole column using python panda or any other better library and write it to existing excel file.
The excel formula is:

```
=IF(AND(J2="SC",J3="EUS),K3-K2,"")
```

or

```
=IF(AND(currentRowOfCol J="SC",NextRowOfCol J="EUS),NextRowOfCol K-CurrentRowOfCol K,"")
```

Sample:

```
index J K
  1   2 3
  2   2 5
  3   7 2
```

Result Should be:

```
index J     K   L
  1   SC    4   1  
  2   EUS   5  NULL
  3   SC    2  NULL
```

---

Tried this code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Sameer/Desktop/abc.xlsx')
Sheet = wb['Data Owner Group History']

for cellObj in list(Sheet.columns)[12]:
#    print(n)
    j1=('J'+str(cellObj.row))
    j2 = ('J'+str((cellObj.row)+1))
    y=('K'+(str((cellObj.row)+1)))
    k=('K2'+(str(cellObj.row)))
    n='IF(AND({0}="SC",{1}="EUS-CUC-DISPATCH (Ceryx/Amdocs group)"),{2}- 
    {3},"")'.format(j1,j2,y,k)
    cellObj.value = n
    wb.save("C:/Users/Sameer/Desktop/result.xlsx")
print("done")
```

Buts it gets stuck at executing and never executes last command print("done"). It creates a result file but that is damaged and contains nothing. Will be better if someone can implement it using pandas so that the operation can be faster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you include a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [mcve] and what you have tried so far

Comment: Edited post with more details. Please assist.

Comment: You have the whole power of `python` at your disposal. Why try to make up an excel formula and use it in excel? Just save your `xlsx` after all the logic. I Didn't understand very well what you're trying to do, especially the `J2` and `J3` part. Are you only looking to the `2nd` and `3rd` rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `np.where` with `shift`

```
np.where((df.J.eq('SC'))&(df.J.shift(-1).eq('EUS')),df.K.shift(-1)-df.K,None)
Out[7]: array([1.0, None, None], dtype=object)
```

---

```
df['L']=np.where((df.J.eq('SC'))&(df.J.shift(-1).eq('EUS')),df.K.shift(-1)-df.K,None)
df
Out[9]: 
   index    J  K     L
0      1   SC  4     1
1      2  EUS  5  None
2      3   SC  2  None
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Appreciate the help. But i am having one issue, In Column J i need to put date and time ex., 2017-01-01 16:32:31. The result of subtraction should be in this format: 00:01:37

Comment: @ShazibMunshi convert it after we have the new column , you can look at pd.to_datetime

Comment: I tried some ways, but i keep getting error "Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta"using numpy library and "time data -236449951000000000 does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)" using panda library. The results we get in column L by subtracting rows of datetime format are in format (-2.3645E+17
). Hence no datetime function is working for me.